# Separating elements from relations over groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, relations, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Under what condition(s) we can separate group elements from a system of relations?

For example, if we have the relations $g_{1}^{3}g_{2}^{2}g_{1}g_{2} = 1$, and $g_{2}g_{1}g_{2}g_{1} = 1$ then it is certain that we can separate $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ from the given two relations, and after separating them, we will have $g_{1}^{2} = 1$ and $g_{2} = 1$.

So for some relations $f_{1}, f_{2}, \ldots, f_{n}$ and for some group elements $g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots, g_{n}$ if we have $f_{1}(g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots, g_{n}) = 1, f_{2}(g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots, g_{n}) = 1 \ldots, f_{n}(g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots, g_{n}) = 1 $, then under what condition(s) we can separate $g_{1}, g_{2}, \ldots, g_{n}$ from the relations $f_{1}, f_{2}, \ldots, f_{n}$?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "separate:" An example is not enough. Also, questions of the type "under what conditions..." tend not to have clear answers.

Comment: I think it's probably fair to say that, as a general statement, any well-defined question about finite presentations is undecideable.

Comment: That is not true. For example, the problem if the group  is perfect is decidable.

Comment: @JCAA Its not true in general, but it is a decent guiding principal. (There is a nice Gromov quote addressing this, although I forget it.)

Comment: @user1729: The Gromov quote which you forgot is not about this. Your are trying to trivialize a nontrivial subject.

Comment: @JCAA I don't think claiming that this is a "decent guiding principal" is trivialising the subject. Yes, there are decidable problems, and yes the topic is complex, but most common problems about presentations are undecidable in general (notably Dehn's 3 problems), and in particular the majority of such problems which are asked here are undecidable.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be asking whether, from the presentation of $G$, you can determine the orders of the generators. The answer is 'no'. In general, it is an insoluble problem to determine whether a group given by generators and relations is the trivial group.